# Disable a link if the date has not yet been reached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a little advent calendar with certain functionalities. I've got it to be be responsive, flip on hover and open a little modal box on click. The only thing I'm struggling with (not that the rest wasn't) is to make it so that each box is only active on the actual date (or prior date); i.e. the first five days will be able to open on the 5th December.

Is this possible the way that I've built it?

Here's the code so far:

```js
/*
var now = new Date();
    var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var idate1 = new Date('10/29/2017');
var idate2 = new Date('10/30/2017');

if(today.getTime() == idate1.getTime()) {
document.getElementById("i1").innerHTML = 'Yesterday';
}
if(today.getTime() == idate2.getTime()) {
document.getElementById("i2").innerHTML = 'Today';
}
*/

var now = new Date();
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var idate1 = new Date('10/29/2017');
var idate2 = new Date('10/30/2017');
var idate3 = new Date('10/31/2017');


if (today.getTime() == idate1.getTime()) {
  //alert('It's the 29th');
  document.getElementById("1stDayActive").disabled = true;
}
if (today.getTime() == idate2.getTime()) {
  alert('It'
    s the 30 th ');
    document.getElementById("2ndDayActive").disabled = true;
  }
  if (today.getTime() == idate3.getTime()) {
    //alert('It's the 31st');
    document.getElementById("3rdDayActive").disabled = true;
  }
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px
}

.demo-3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px
}

.demo-3 figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -50px
}

.demo-3 figure img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: -15px 0
}

.demo-3 figure figcaption {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.demo-3 figure h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left
}

.demo-3 figure p {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left
}

.demo-3 figure figcaption {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 29px 44px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 76, 110, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s
}

.demo-3 figure img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s
}

.demo-3 figure:hover img,
figure.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

.demo-3 figure:hover figcaption,
figure.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0)
}

a {
  display: block
}


/* MODAL BOX*/

.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Raleway:400,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="demo-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <a href="#1stDay"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" / id="1stDayActive">
            <figcaption>
              <h2>The 1st Day of Christmas</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="1stDay" class="modalDialog">
      <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>The 1st Day of Christmas</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
        <p><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="demo-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <a href="#2ndDay"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" / id="2ndDayActive">
            <figcaption>
              <h2>The 2nd Day of Christmas</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="2ndDay" class="modalDialog">
      <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>The 2nd Day of Christmas</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
        <p><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="demo-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <a href="#3rdDay"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" / id="3rdDayActive">
            <figcaption>
              <h2>The 3rd Day of Christmas</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="3rdDay" class="modalDialog">
      <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>The 3rd Day of Christmas</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
        <p><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, the live link is http://advent-calendar.trainstorm.co.uk/flip2.html

Comment: And I've taken out the rogue comma in the "alert"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable a link in this way. You should stop click event from firing:

```
if (today.getTime() == idate2.getTime()) {
    alert('It\'s the 30 th ');
    document.getElementById("2ndDayActive").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

OR You can use `pointer-events: none;` :

```
a.disabled {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

and in your js:

```
if (today.getTime() == idate2.getTime()) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("2ndDayActive");
    elem.className += " disabled";
}
```

But before that you have to tell browser to run javascript code after the page has been loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>Advent Calendar</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Raleway:400,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<style>
    ...
</style>
</head>
<body>

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
         (function () {
              // place your js code here
         })();
    </script>
</body>
```

note the place of js code.

Comment: That's absolutely awesome. I was so close but so far away! It works a dream now. My kids will be delighted when I unveil this to them. Thank you.